# how to use ng switch to better validate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, switch-statement

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/AbmsG/1/

I only want to show error messages one at a time. I am thinking of doing it with `ng switch` which is more code efficient than `ng:show`, however the algorithm I have right now does not currently work.

```
<div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="true">
    <div ng-switch-when="form.LastName.$error.required" style="color: white; background-color: red">required</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="form.LastName.$error.len" style="color: white; background-color: red">len</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="form.LastName.$error.dallas" style="color: white; background-color: red">dallas</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? You might have to single-quote 'background-color'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the `ng-switch` logic backwards. `on` holds the expression to evaluate and the `when`s hold what to match. You may not want to do it this way, but this shows what I mean:

```
<div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="form.LastName.$error.required">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" style="color: white; background-color: red">required</div>
</div>
<div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="form.LastName.$error.len">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" style="color: white; background-color: red">len</div>
</div>
<div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="form.LastName.$error.dallas">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" style="color: white; background-color: red">dallas</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AbmsG/3/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons this fails.

`ng-switch-when` expects a string. So the first case, for example, is being compared to the string literal "form.LastName.$error.required", not the object property of the same name.

In contrast, `ng-switch` expects an expression. The only case that will match the `on` expression `true`, is the string literal "true".

This would work instead although without the exact behavior you want:

```
<div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="form.LastName.$error.required">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" style="color: white; background-color: red">required</div>
</div>
<div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="form.LastName.$error.len">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" style="color: white; background-color: red">len</div>
</div>
<div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="form.LastName.$error.dallas">
    <div ng-switch-when="true" style="color: white; background-color: red">dallas</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As dnc253 said your `ng-switch` logic is a bit off. The following will give you the exact functionality you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/AbmsG/4/

**HTML**

```
<form ng-app="someApp" name="form" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input validate name="LastName" ng-model="form.lastName" dallas len = "5" required />
  <div class="errorDiv" ng-switch on="currentError">
    <div ng-switch-when="required" style="color: white; background-color: red">required</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="len" style="color: white; background-color: red">len</div>
    <div ng-switch-when="dallas" style="color: white; background-color: red">dallas</div>
  </div> 
</form>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('someApp', [])
  .directive('validate', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',        
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      element.bind("keydown keypress", function(event) {
          if (event.which === 13) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                  scope.$eval(attrs.onEnter);
              });
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      });
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function(val){
          if (!val) val = '';
          ctrl.$setValidity('required',
                             val != '');
          ctrl.$setValidity('len',
                              val.length == 5);
            ctrl.$setValidity('dallas',
                   val=='dallas');
            return val;
        });
    }
}
}).controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('form.$error', function (errObj) {
    if (errObj.required) $scope.currentError = "required";
      else if (errObj.len) $scope.currentError = "len";
      else if (errObj.dallas) $scope.currentError = "dallas";
  }, true);
}]);
```

Comment: What's up with `!!errObj.required`?  What does that catch that simply `if (errObj.required)` doesn't?

Comment: thanks, I used this one last time, thought there might be a shorter answer. Btw when you do $watch(obj, func, true), how deep does the $watch go? I mean does it watch form.$error.obj1.obj2 if I do $watch('form.$error')

Comment: @Langdon Yeah no need for that anymore. Carryover from another approach I took. I updated my answer to remove as to not cause confusion.

Comment: @user2167582 I believe it goes as deep as the object's deepest child. If for some reason that's an issue, you could watch the 3 fields individually, but something tells me that's more work than this is worth and there won't be much of any performance difference.